# Caching of partial documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm pretty familiar how the caching works in MongoDB in relation to memory-mapped files by the OS. However, I'm more interested in the details of it...

Let's say, I have this format of documents in one collection:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("..."),
  first_name: "x",
  last_name: "y",
  email: "z"
}
```

1. If `findOne({_id: ObjectId("...")})` command is executed, then the whole document will be put in the cache. After this, if I run `findOne({_id: ObjectId("...")}, {email: 1})`, is the cache going to be used (note that in this last command I'm only interested in the email field)?
2. If I issue `findOne({_id: ObjectId("...")}, {first_name: 1, last_name: 1})`, is the whole document put into cache, or just the projected fields? In other words, if I run `findOne({_id: ObjectId("...")})` after the previous command, will the cache be used?

Thanks,
Zlatko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your query is satisfied by an index alone (i.e. using a [covered index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries)), then any action that loads part of the document will page the whole thing into memory.  Hence, the document will be in the cache when you re-run and alter the fields returned.

Using the projection to restrict to certain fields just means it just won't return the fields you are not specifying (therefore it is more efficient in terms of data returned, particularly if you have large fields you aren't using).

Note: your question has me thinking about docs that span multiple pages, and whether than might make a difference - something I will need to research/test, which may be interesting.

However, strictly speaking, what gets put into the cache is not just dictated by the document, or the index being used.  [Readahead](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Notes#ProductionNotes-Readahead) will also play into it (for Linux at least), and you will be reading in full 4k pages, regardless of your document size, so there may be an element of inefficiency there.  Exactly how much depends on your document size and level of fragmentation.  Lots more discussion on that topic to be found here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/408100/mongodb-and-datasets-that-dont-fit-in-ram-no-matter-how-hard-you-shove/408182#408182

Comment: Thanks, this is really what I wanted to know!